# Setup page not getting loaded after install

Tags: magento2, composer

I have been trying to **install** magento 2,

When i am trying to access the setup page from url, but the url is not accessible it says

> This page isn’t working xx.xx.xxx.xxx is currently unable to handle
>   this request. HTTP ERROR 500

I have no idea what the problem is apache2 is running properly I am able to access other pages like phpinfo.

Any help or pointers will be really appreciated.

Comment: This will help you `https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105821/magento-2-not-working-on-apache2-php7-and-ubuntu`